# I want to trigger button not only with click but with enter

Tags: java, jframe, keylistener

I made a "game" with an interface where you could guess a random number. You have to click a button to submit your guess and to get an answer from the console (I use eclipse). But now I want to trigger the button by clicking enter. Here is the code of my Program (I know I don't need this many imports but I tried a lot of stuff):

```
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JRootPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import java.util.Scanner;
   public class UIZahlRaten{

    static int meineZahl = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(100);
    static int AnzVersuche = 0;
    static JLabel text = new JLabel ("Bitte geben sie eine Zahl ein: ");
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         
        openUI();
        
    }
    
    
    
    public static void openUI() {
        
        JFrame frame = new JFrame ("Rate die Zahl");
        frame.setSize(370, 140);
        frame.setLocation(500, 300);
        JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        JTextField textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setBounds(8,50,237,30);
        
        JButton button = new JButton("Abschicken");
        button.setBounds(247, 50, 101, 29);
        
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String text = textField.getText();
                 int zahl =  Integer.parseInt(text);
                 AnzVersuche++;
                 raten(zahl);
                 
            }
        });
        text.setBounds(7,20,200,20);
        
        
        frame.add(button);
        frame.add(text);
        frame.setLayout(null);
        frame.add(textField);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        
        
    }

    
    public static void naechsteRunde() {
        AnzVersuche++;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Bitte geben sie eine Zahl ein: ");
        int zahl = scanner.nextInt();
        raten(zahl);
    }
    
    public static void raten(int zahl) {
        
        if (zahl == meineZahl) {
            
            System.out.println("Richtig geraten! Sie haben " + AnzVersuche + " Versuche gebraucht");
        }
        else if(zahl > meineZahl) {
            System.out.println("Die Zahl ist kleiner");
            }   
        else {
            System.out.println("Die Zahl ist groesser");
        }
        if(zahl != meineZahl) {
        text.setText("Bitte erneut raten");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean, somebody is typing in the text field and then they type "enter" and it should fire the action?

Comment: I *think* you can add an action listener to your textfield and that action will be fired with you press enter. You could even add the same action listener that you add to the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add in openUI() an action listener like:

```
Action action = new AbstractAction()
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            System.out.println("some action");
            System.out.println("value: " + textField.getText());
        }
    };

    textField.addActionListener( action );
```